# Heap at 30M after setContentView

Tags: android, heap-memory, mat

When starting my Application, the heap is at about 15M. After calling `setContentView` in `MainActivity` it raises to about 30M. There isn't much in that layout. That's why I'm wondering if that's normal. When starting another Acticity, it again raises to about 40M and won't go down again.

That's what `main.xml` looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinLAdMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/StartButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/HighscoreButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/SettingsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm using a background-drawable. But the file is about 60K big..

And that's what the MAT-default-report looks like right after `setContentView()`:

[image: screenshot]

This is what the paths to GC look like (excluding weak references):

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

These "nexts" end in head class java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference, which is telling me nothing.

As I said, it's getting worse with every Activity. For example after 
Main->Highscore->GlobalHighscore it's no more possible to start the Activity "ingame".
Hope you guys can help me :).

If you need more Information / Code, tell me.

Comment: File size does not matter since that is compressed. You have 15MB raw image data in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image file formats like PNG and JPG are using a compression algorithm to reduce the used disk space. However when images are loaded in android app these files are decompressed and may become much bigger then the original file.

The space used after decompression would be similar to the disk space used if you convert your PNG or JPG file to BMP 32 bits color.

**An example**

A very simple full white draw with size 1024 x 1024 pixels, saved as PNG will use a few Kb.

After decompression into a ARGB_8888 it becomes an array of 1024 x 1024 x 4 bytes (the last 4 stands for the 4 bytes used per pixel, one for each basic color RGB and one for Alpha)

```
1024 x 1024 x 4 = 4,194,304 = 4 MB
```

so the memory used will be 4 MB for this simple image.

**What to do**

Reduce de memory used by image:

- Use the smallest size (width and height) that still meet your
  requirements for the different screen sizes you want to support
- Use different sizes for different screens (mdpi, hdpi, etc.). However, this increases your application size.
- Use Draw 9 Patch to create small size images that will extend to large screen in a predictable  and controlled way.

Find the memory leak that keeps memory aloocation increasing.

Probably you are using some reference to your activity `Context` that is preventing GC to collect the memory. The most probable reasons are objects that have reference to Context/Activity:

- Threads
- Handlers
- Views

Try nulling them when no longer required, or on activity `OnDestroy()`

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. The logo has a resolution of 600 x 200 and the background 720 x 1280. The three buttons 200 x 55 each. So the memory used had to be about 4.3 MB. So why is MAT telling something about 14 MB? I am also using something like this: `public class MyApp extends Application{

 public HighscoreList localHighscore;` and this to get access to it: `(MyApp) getApplication()).localHighscore.getLocalHighscore()`. Could that be the problem? **Sorry about the bad formatting, but i'm new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: It could be. Try the following: Make localHighscore static, and access it using  `MyApp.localHighscore`.

Comment: The best way to find what's keeps object referenced is in MAT, select `Historigram`, and you can see the top memory comsuption objects and how many copies you have of them by selecting object, right click and choose `List Objects`and `with incoming referencs`. Finally, order by size and select select one object, right click and `Path to GC Root` and `exclude weak/soft references`. You will end with the references that are preventing this object to be collected by GC.

Comment: Thanks. I tried making it static, but the problem still exists. I updated my post and added what you said (MAT). Where can i see, which reference actually is preventing GC to do it's work? And what to do, when localized?

Comment: I've looked through the list, and I didn't find any object belonging to your application package. In general, you should be able to find it, and it should give you a hint where to look further. Are you using Handler or Thread class in your code?

Comment: I'm using Handler class. But even when commenting out every line of "custom code" in MainAcrivity, (btw. there isn't even a second Thread in Main), MAT looks just the same :/

Comment: I'm getting confused. You need to split the 2 problems. Problem 1: you want to understand the relationship between your drawables dimensions and memory allocation. Problem 2: everytime you restart your activity, memory allocation keeps growing.

Comment: Problem 1: When you start your app for the first time after a fresh install, the memory allocated by bitmaps should be aligned with your bitmaps dimensions. If not, review in MAT what objects and sizes have been allocated.

Comment: Problem 2: Do you still have this one? Here the problem probably has nothing to do with bitmaps. Only because bitmap is large, makes the problem more noticable. You refered that you use Handler, and any message posted to an Handler will have a link to the Context. Only after message is consumed, the link will go way. If this is not solving and you can't identify the root cause in MAT list, try commenting one by one the most problematic objects (handlers, views, static objects, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I think i got it now. The heap now stays at around 20 MB when moving through the Activities. What i did: I created the images for every dimension (mdpi, hdpi..) just like you told me in your fisrt answer :). I guess it allocated so much memory because of scaling or whatever. So thanks again, Luis. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `android:src="@drawable/logo"` and resize it manually to just fit your screen, needs. I mean the logo.png in drawable folder. In a 320x480 resolution it not needed a 2560x1600 pixel one!

Comment: Thank you. But the logo already is at 600 x 200. Is that too big?

Comment: 600x200x4=480.000 byte, that is not 15-30 millions, you have something else nasty there...

Comment: As mentioned above, additionally i have the background plus three buttons (600x200 + 200x55 + 200x55 + 200x55 + 720x1280) x 4 = ~ 4.3 M. Really can't figure out where the problem is.